# How to kill buffers when quitting a client frame in emacs daemon

Tags: macos, emacs, daemon, emacsclient

I'm using `emacs` as a daemon on OSX ML.

When I close an instance `emacsclient -t`, I'd like emacs to kill all the buffers I've opened within the instance of emacsclient.

Doing `C-x C-c` or `C-x 5 0` does not work: buffers will remain open in the daemon, so after a while I have 50+ buffers opened and I'm completely lost.

**How to close all buffers and then quit an instance of emacsclient?**

Comment: When you finish editing a file opened with `emacsclient`, are you using the command `C-x #` to exit?

Comment: No, I just used C-x C-s + C-x k but C-x # is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.